# Ajax live edit is not wotking and got an 500 (Internal Server Error)?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

i'm trying to modify a product but when i click the button a got that *500 (Internal Server Error)*

this is ajax method

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    fetch_customer_data();



    $(document).on('click', '#btnModify', function(){

var name = $('#Name2').text();
var title = $('#Title2').text();
var mainPrice = $('#MainPrice2').text();
var discount = $('#DiscountPrice2').text();
var StockQ = $('#StockQuantity2').text();
var Desc = $('#Discription2').text();
var Features = $('#Features2').text();

var id = $("#id2").text();

if(name != ' ')
{

 $.ajax({
  url:"/Product/Update",
  method:"POST",
  data:{name:name, title:title , name:name , mainPrice:mainPrice , discount:discount ,StockQ:StockQ , Desc:Desc , Features:Features,  id:id, _token:_token},

  success:function(data)
  {
    fetch_customer_data();
  }
 });


}
else
{
    alert('Something went wrong');
}
});
```

and this is the edit function

```
 public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $data = array([
                'Name'       =>  $request->name,
                'Title'       =>  $request->title,
                'MainPrice'       =>  $request->mainPrice,
                'DiscountPrice'       =>  $request->discount,
                'StockQuantity'       =>  $request->StockQ,
                'Discription'       =>  $request->Desc,
                'Features'       =>  $request->Features
                ]
            );

            DB::table('products')
                ->where('id', $request->id)
                ->update($data);
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Data Updated</div>';
        }
    }
```

Route :
*Route::post('/Product/Update', [ProductsController::class, 'edit']);*

Comment: Go check what the error log has to say first of all. (And next time, please do that _before_ you come asking about a 500 Internal Server error.)

Comment: Ajax will only work when full of process will be completed means either you get success or error in ajax function then it will give you some other http code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = array(
            'Name'       =>  $request->name,
            'Title'       =>  $request->title,
            'MainPrice'       =>  $request->mainPrice,
            'DiscountPrice'       =>  $request->discount,
            'StockQuantity'       =>  $request->StockQ,
            'Discription'       =>  $request->Desc,
            'Features'       =>  $request->Features
        )
```

because you are using multi dimensional array instead of 2d array

maybe this will helpful